# Can any SQL-Azure DB be hosted by Windows Azure Marketplace/DataMarket?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-marketplace

Our customer has a daily 4 gig data file (.csv) file to be uploaded in a blob storage (Windows Azure).

After upload (by a web role) we want the csv file to be processed to a SQL Azure database (processing/converting is done by a worker role).

After processing, it must be consumed by Microsoft Azure Marketplace / Data Market.

Unfortunately, the information for content providers (like us in this case) is very spare.

My question to be answered is: Can any SQL Azure database be hosted in Windows Azure MarketPlace/Data Market ? Or even better: what are the requirements for content providers regarding SQL Azure DB's ?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the [Data Publishing Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=221324&clcid=0x409)?

Comment: Yes, I just found the questionaire. Very thorough, but I think it should be possible to have Data Market hosting the SQL Azure DB and have daily data updates.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question strictly speaking, no. You cannot have your database hosted in the marketplace. With regards to your second question, you need to supply the DataMarket team the valid parameters for data retrieval and the connection strings to your service.

Comment: Indeed. Marketplace is just a commercial wrapper around your own hosted services. We are hosting SQL Azure + OData services in Azure and are looking for Data Market for commercial publishing and billing.  Data Market can page your responses up to 100 rows, that is convienient.